# How to share Word documents based on same template (.dotm) between Word 2010 and Word 2011 users on a network?

Tags: windows, macos, networking, microsoft-word, templates

I have a large problem in sharing a Word template (more precisely; the rendered document from the template) between Windows (Word 2010) and Mac (Word 2010) users on a network.

In my test environment I have a 
*Win x64 7 computer with Word 2010
*Mac computer with Word 2011
*a shared network drive with my template file

My Word 2010 configuration: File > Options > Advanced > General | File Locations... > Workgroup templates > Modify > "\AF-02004\Users\PublicWordTemplate" (a network shared folder):
[image: PC: Workgroup TemplateFile Location]

My Word 2011 configuration: Word > Preferences > File Locations > Workgroup templates > Modify > "Users:Public:WordTemplate"
[image: Mac: Workgroup Template File Location]

**Problem:**
When i create a document in Word 2011 based on my common work group template (from the shared network drive) and take a copy of that document (.docx) to my Windows computer and open it in Word 2010, i have full access to all my macros.

When I edit the document in Word 2010 (Windows), save it, and take the document (.docx) back to Word 2011, there are no macro functionality any more! I can also see that the Document template folder has been changed!

[image: Template folder has been changed!]

That's not the folder I initially adressed...

Comment: Are you saving the template as a "Word Macro-Enabled Template"? I'm guessing the security is more strict on the Mac version.

Comment: Hi Mat, yes, I initially created the Word documents based on same template .dotm. -.dotm means macro enabled. I'm quite sure that the problem has something to do with that Word 2010 assigns its own path to the workgroup template? (a windows location doesn't look like a mac location?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question since I got an answer on another forum: (just in case if there is someone else who runs into this nasty issue): [Don't share documents based on macro templates between different versions of word!](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/how-to-share-word-documents-based-on-same-template/d657a6a4-78cd-468d-9268-feae588b1027?tm=1395358670824)